# Magento: How to override admin controller outside of adminhtml?

Tags: magento, controller, overriding

Simply put, I want to override ProcessController which is in the Mage/Index/controllers/Admninhtml/ProcessController.php.

I know how to override the front-end controller, but this gives me a headache for hours now. I can't put it to work. Here's my config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
<global>
    <models>
        <twobuy_index>
            <class>Twobuy_Index_Model</class>
        </twobuy_index>                 
    </models>
</global>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <index>
            <args>
                <modules>
                     <Twobuy before="Mage_Index">Twobuy_Index</Twobuy>
                </modules>
            </args>            
        </index>
    </routers>
</admin>
</config>
```

And the controller declaration

```
 include_once('Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php');
 class Twobuy_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController extends Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController
 {
```

I tried overriding reindexAction, but my method never gets called.

Comment: solved it! It was the <adminhtml> tags, but I had to override the Mage_Index_Adminhtml with Twobuy_Index_Adminhtml.

Thanks everybody for help! I wish Magento is a little bit better documented, with explanations, not only examples, so we wouldn't have to lucky guess solutions.

Comment: how you had extended? i also want to extend similar like you.
Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
My config.xml is:

<config>
<modules> 
<DS_Adminextended> 
<version>1.0.0</version> 
</DS_Adminextended> 
 </modules>
<admin>
<routers>
 <adminhtml>
<args>
<modules>
<DS_Adminextended before="Mage_Adminhtml">DS_Adminextended</DS_Adminextended>
</modules>
</args>
</adminhtml>
</routers>
</admin>
</config> 

My Extended controller class not called.

class DS_Adminextended_Adminhtml_Oauth_AuthorizeController extends Mage_Oauth_Adminhtml_Oauth_AuthorizeController {
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `<index>` with `<adminhtml>` in your config file. It might just be a copy-paste error but your `<Twobuy>` tag is incorrectly ended with `</Ucon>`.

Comment: tnx for the answer, but the index->adminhtml switch didn't help :( the Twobuy tag was just copy-paste, it's correct in my config

Answer (score 2):

`<Twobuy before="Mage_Index">Twobuy_Index</Ucon>`

Looks like an error in your XML

`<twobuy_index before="Mage_Index">Twobuy_Index</twobuy_index>`

Comment: tnx for answer, that was ok in my file, only copy/paste mistake. I tried with what you suggest too, didn't help